# Problems with converting text to .arff in Weka

Tags: text, dataset, weka, arff

I am trying to convert a text file with 1000 social media post for sentiment analysis purposes using Weka SimpleCLI using : java weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader -dir /directory/with/your/text/files > output.arff

However I get an exception. Does anyone know what the problem is? Screenshot is in the link.

[Screenshot of the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ7h9.png)

CODE:

```
> java weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader -dir /Users/Nenad/Desktop/Sentiment > sentiment.arff

@relation C__Users_Nenad_Desktop_Sentiment

@attribute text string
@attribute @@class@@ {}

@data

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader.getNextInstance(TextDirectoryLoader.java:568)
    weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader.run(TextDirectoryLoader.java:693)
    weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader.main(TextDirectoryLoader.java:654)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    weka.gui.SimpleCLIPanel$ClassRunner.run(SimpleCLIPanel.java:328)

    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader.getNextInstance(TextDirectoryLoader.java:568)
    at weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader.run(TextDirectoryLoader.java:693)
    at weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader.main(TextDirectoryLoader.java:654)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weka.gui.SimpleCLIPanel$ClassRunner.run(SimpleCLIPanel.java:328)
```

Comment: Please paste the exception text, don't include screenshots. Also please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello I've added the code sorry.